# Loading the whole graph DB in memory using Tinkerpop3

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I'm using Tinkerpop3 to access a Neo4J DB with 1-2 GB size. Speed is very important and I want to load the whole graph in RAM, is there any way to load the graph in RAM? I already use indexing, so I don't want indexing, I want the whole graph DB in memory

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could iterate the entire graph to warm the caches.  So basically, do `g.V()` and `g.E()`.

Comment: How big is the catch size ? is there any control over the size of it?

Comment: Neo4j has a number of settings with respect to memory and caching: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-io-examples.html http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-jvm.html http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-caches.html